# Parse Jsp file and find specific tags using Java

Tags: java, jsp, search, tags, expression

I need a way to find specific tags in my class.

Example code :

```
<ace:column id="test1"></ace:column>                        
<ace:column id="test2"></ace:column>                        
<ice:panelGrid id="test3" columns="4" />
```

Now I want to process the file with above contents ,parse it and get all the tag values with identifier "id".

I would expect to get

```
test1
test2
test3
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using [JSPs with XML syntax](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/11/28/jsp_xml.html) you can just use an XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

Use parsers. There are a lot of and for the tutorial on how to parse [see this URL.](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to process the tags themselves, you would need to rely on some parser such as [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

That being said, **if all you want** are the values following the `id` string, you could rely on regular expressions, somthing such as: `id="([^"]*?)"`.

Comment: JSoup is `html` parser. It doesn't not support `jsp`. However you can parse but that's error prone.